# How to stop NextJS including dynamically imported component in main _app.js bundle when using Module Aliases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, import

I am converting some shared-ui components to dynamically imported ones. (NextJS 11)

I have module aliases setup using **@nx/next:library**, e.g. `@my-site/shared-ui`, with all being exported from an `index.ts`, e.g.

```
export { default as MobileTabs } from './components/MobileTabs'
```

and imported in a page like

```
const MobileTabs = dynamic(
  () => import('@my-site/shared-ui').then((module) => module.MobileTabs),
)
```

The issue I have is I am not getting the chunk when building or viewing the app; it's still being included in the main _app.js.

I have tried to use *relative imports* by removing the default export from the index.ts and *it works* but I now cannot build due to eslint complaining, and I would like to continue using the module alias export.

Could this be a problem with tree-shaking and webpack...? Or am I missing something to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be rendering the dynamically imported component conditionally.

```
const MobileTabs = dynamic(
  () => import('@my-site/shared-ui').then((module) => module.MobileTabs),
)

...
{ someCondition ? <MobileTabs /> : null }
```